# latest image upload asp.net 2.0 applet

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, asp.net-2.0

I use the following coding to show six images from the latest photo album i uploaded picture to. However the images being shown are the 1st six images in the folder (which are the ones the oldest uploaded) not the final six images uploaded.
**Anyone can help me what should i change in the following coding to show the last six images in the folder.**

```
               <%
                            latestfolder = "na"
                            latestdate = cdate("01/01/09")

                            set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("images/gallery"))
                            for each folder in fo.subfolders 
                                if cdate(folder.DateLastModified) > latestdate then
                                    latestdate = cdate(folder.DateLastModified)
                                    latestfolder = folder.name
                                end if
                            next

                            if latestfolder <> "na" then
                              set fi=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("images/gallery/" & latestfolder))
                                looptimes = 0
                                for each file in fi.files 

    if right(lcase(file.Name),3) = "jpg" then %>

 <a href="thumbnail.aspx?picture=<%=server.URLEncode("images/gallery/" & latestfolder & "/" & file.Name)%>&maxWidth=640&maxHeight=480" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;">          
   <img src="thumbnail.aspx?picture=<%=server.URLEncode("images/gallery/" & latestfolder & "/" & file.Name)%>&maxWidth=100&maxHeight=60" style="border:1px solid #ffffff; margin:5px; margin-top:14px;">        </a> 

  <% end if

                                    looptimes = looptimes + 1
                                    if looptimes = 6 then exit for end if
                                next

                            end if
                    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuck! With that said...it looks like you are sorting your folders based on date, but not your files.